# Inheritance withheld due to taxes from USA

Tags: international-transfer, inheritance

My girlfriends dad died last year and left her a sum of money through a company called fidelity. She received a lump sum but some of the money was withheld pending her father's tax return. She was told it would be paid to her after the new year once her late fathers tax return was done, however she has now been asked by th IRS to do a tax return. She has never earned money from america and we cant find anyone to get advice of what to do. Please help!

Comment: Where is your girlfriend located?

Comment: Need to clarify whether the tax return the IRS is asking for is for your girlfriend, or for her deceased father.

Comment: She is in england, and they are asking her to fill in a tax return. She has never lived in the states though

Comment: Is gf a US citizen? If she was born to a US parent, even though she didn't and doesn't live in the US she may still be a citizen under the law, and US citizens living _anywhere_ are subject to 'resident' (domestic) tax -- US is almost the only country that does this, making it unfamiliar and strange to most other people.

Answer (score 5):

First question is who is the executor of the estate?  Typically it falls upon that person to do things like file the final tax return.  If it is your girlfriend, then she should do so.

What I would do is contact a person in the state where her father lived to do the tax returns.  Most of the work can be done online.  A couple of products to look at are TurboTax and H&R Block.  Unless there were a lot of complexities, it is mostly answering a few questions, with the appropriate tax forms in front of you, and doing some data entry.  Many Americans are capable of doing their tax returns on their mobile phones.  The cost is pretty low to use most services.

Fidelity may not be the only place where you may need to gather information from which will complicate the matter.

The key question is, is your girl friend the executor?  If not who is?

Comment: Re "products", many people can use the IRS's on-line Free File system instead of paying money for 3rd party products.

Comment: No she isnt. She was told that the money was held in case her father owed any tax, and that once his return is done, her money would be released. The taxes have been filed and done but the money has not been released, and she has been sent around in circles since by its and fidelity

Comment: Fidelity has excellent customer service.  So provided you supply the right documentation the funds should be released soon.

Comment: @PeteB. If the account is a retirement account, 401k, IRA, does she have to file a personal tax return as the money is counted as income?

Comment: It is a retirement account, but his wife got the 401k. This is a personal saving retirement account. She has never lived in america or earned in america and therefore never had anything to do with paying taxes in america. Her dads tax returns are up to date and everything has been paid.

Comment: @Nick Andrews: By "personal saving", do you mean an IRA?  If so, the situation is explained.  (I think: I am not an expert on this.)  Money in an IRA (Independent Retirement Account) is not taxed until it is withdrawn, when it is treated as ordinary income.  If she inherited the IRA, she now has US source income, and so must pay taxes on it.  But she may have the option of withdrawing over several years, which would lower the tax.

Comment: @jamesqf+ _Individual_ Retirement _Arrangement_. There are two kinds of IRA: traditional and Roth. Money in a trad IRA is _usually_ taxed at withdrawal (as ordinary income) but there are exceptions;

Comment: Please don't use turbotax or H&R Block. Both of those companies are the reason filing taxes is so hard in the first place. They literally spend millions of dollars every year making sure that tax filing isn't getting easier.